# Transition on SVG Transform property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have got svg elements that have transition working on transform by hovering the element.

Problem: Edge doesn't support transform in css for SVG's.

We can set attribute on SVG on Edge `transform="translate(50 50)"`

I want to run that transform smoothly with transition. Is there any way to do that?

[Link](http://dev.openform.pl/newsen)

Here you can see the problem, try to hover TOP/RIGHT/BOTTOM/LEFT element of navigation.

Comment: you could do the transition in SMIL and then use [fakeSmile](https://leunen.me/fakesmile/) to enable SMIL in IE

Comment: any tips? i've never hear about  that

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Edit: SMIL works in IE but not on Edge. I want it working on Edge, not IE

Comment: SMIL is neither supported by IE, nor Edge natively. FakeSmile is a polyfill that can add support to either.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html is the SMIL chapter for SVG

Comment: Thanks guys! You can post SMIL comment as answer and i will accept that, it works for me!